# Will IE 11 support WebGL 1.0 and extentions?

Tags: internet-explorer, webgl

As I see IE 11 Preview don't support WebGL 1.0. Will IE 11 support WebGL 1.0? 
Here is a link [Microsoft connect IE bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/795172/ie11-fails-more-than-half-tests-in-official-webgl-conformance-test-suite)

Is it possible ask Microsoft to resolve this issue?

Comment: It is definitely possible to ask, did you have any particular use-case that is failing ?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to discuss this with Microsoft connect forums or appropriate other venues. SO is not the place to discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 now supports WebGL. But the Version is not WebGL 1.0, it is WebGl 0.93 (On Windows 8.1 Update 1 build 17025). I hope Microsoft will make WebGL up to 1.0.

Some IE 11 WebGL details:

```
Context Name: experimental-webgl
Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Version:WebGL 0.93
Renderer:Internet Explorer
Shading Language Version:WebGL GLSL ES 0.93
Max Vertex Attribs: 16 
Max Vertex Texture Image Units: 16 
Max Varying Vectors: 14 
Max Uniform Vectors 512 
RGBA Bits: 8, 8, 8, 8 
Max Combined Texture Image Units: 32 
Max Texture Size: 16384 
Max Cube Map Texture Size: 16384 
Num. Compressed Texture Formats: null 
Depth Bits: 24 
Max Render Buffer Size: 16384 
Max Viewport Dimensions: 16384, 16384 
Aliased Line Width Range: 1, 1 
Aliased Point Size Range: 1, 300 
Supported Extensions:
WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc,  
OES_texture_float,  
OES_texture_float_linear,  
EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,  
OES_standard_derivatives
```